# Applying :not(:last-child) to parent class with SCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I have JSX which renders a card-like component:

```
        {userResourceGuides && userResourceGuides.map((guide) => (
          <div className='UserResourceGuides' key={guide.id}>
            <div className='UserResourceGuides__col-1'>
              <h2>{guide.file_label}</h2>
              <p>From: {guide.service_name}</p>
            </div>
            <div className='UserResourceGuides__col-2'>
              <div>
                <a href={guide.file_url} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
                  <span><AiOutlineLink /></span>
                </a>
                <p>View</p>
              </div>

              <div>
                <span><AiOutlineDelete /></span>
                <p>Delete</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

`UserResourceGuides` is the parent class. How can I apply a `:not(:last-child)` selector to this class?

**SCSS**

```
.UserResourceGuides {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem;

  &:not(:last-child) {
    border: 1px solid red; // all entries have border styling applied
  }

  &__col-1 {
    margin-left: 2rem;

    h2 {
      color: $color-blue-subheader;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
    p {
      color: black;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
  }

  &__col-2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 1rem;

...
```

The current styling I have still renders all entries with the border styling applied, and does not exclude the last-child. Not my desired result. What is my error here?

Comment: Use ampersands, just like your other SCSS rules: `&:not(:last-child) { … }` - https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: @Dai I made an edit to the post

Comment: Please show us the final output CSS, and non-React HTML. Have you used your DOM Explorer?